# Smooth user location updates on MapView

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview

In my didUpdateToLocation method i am getting location updates but the move of my current location is some what jerky.

This is the delegate that receives location updates:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation   *)newLoc fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLoc
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = newLoc.coordinate.latitude; 
    region.center.longitude = newLoc.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1;
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Could you please help me determine how to get smooth location updates? I have searched online and found that we can use tracking mode in ios5 to get smooth location update. If that is the case then what changes should I make in my current piece of code.

And if i set 
[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES]; 
in view did load then should i need to set the region again in location update? 
or it will get set automatically since i had used usertrackingmode?

Comment: Can you show the `CLLocationManager` setup code that you use?

Comment: in viewDidLoad i had entered the following code     self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy  =kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

Comment: You might want to move the code in the comment up to the main question so it is clearer for anyone else in the future who finds this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you set the tracking mode you don't need to do any manual region/view setting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My application is tracking the location smoothly now. But i am not getting the updated location on center of the road.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that your iPhone no longer tracks you accurately?

Comment: No, the location updates which i am getting are not appearing at the center of the road.

Comment: And your phone is in the centre of the road when you're testing this? That's not something that you can fix. CoreLocation is doing its best to figure out where you are, most GPSes are only accurate to within 5m or so of the actual position given perfect conditions. And it may be that the maps are wrong anyway.

Comment: Yes the phone was in the center of the road while testing.. so do i need to set the desired accuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters, previously i was setting it to kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation

Comment: BestForNavigation is the most accurate (and power hungry) setting, but it is still going to be a little wrong sometimes. How far out is it?

Comment: Actually the updated point is not present on the center of the road but at the end corner of the road, even though the phone was present at the center while testing.

Comment: The updated coordinates are somewhat 10 meters aways from the actual coordinates which are displayed in google maps app

Comment: If those are the coordinates CoreLocation is giving you then those are the coordinates you have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Although it will drain the battery more quickly (so you shouldn't use it unless you need to), you might find the accuracy improves if you use a different `desiredAccuracy`.

If you refer to Apples list of [Accuracy Constants](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation), you might find `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` or `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` are better options.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. If i set  [self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];              in view did load then should i need to set the region again in location update? or it will get set automatically since i had used usertrackingmode?